# Bitnami Django Stack and module "requests": cannot import name 'certs'

Tags: python, django, python-requests, bitnami

Very specific stuff. I'm running a Bitnami Django stack cloud VM on Amazon. On two different "regular" machines, I could install `requests` by running `sudo pip install requests`, but it seems that Bitname uses it's own specific structure, and something is going wrong when installing `requests` that way. It can also be related to issue [#2028](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2028), but it was fixed long time ago.

I have the following traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://54.94.226.137/

Django Version: 1.7.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'vz_base',
 'vz_api',
 'vz_admin',
 'vz_user')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ProjetoVigZul/ProjetoVigZul/urls.py" in <module>
  5. from vz_api import urls as api_urls
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ProjetoVigZul/vz_api/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from vz_api import views
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ProjetoVigZul/vz_api/views.py" in <module>
  14. from vz_api.dguard import DGuardManager, DGuardIntegrationException
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ProjetoVigZul/vz_api/dguard.py" in <module>
  5. import requests, json
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py" in <module>
  58. from . import utils
File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py" in <module>
  25. from . import certs

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name certs
```

Website is live at http://54.94.226.137/, if anyone is interested.

Comment: You are apparently missing the `/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/certs.py` module.

Comment: It seems so, but the module is there, I just checked its contents... It seems that for some reason the `from . import certs` with the `dot` notation is not working. Some reference problem?

Comment: but the `from . import utils` line (one step up in the traceback) worked just fine.

Comment: What version of requests are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have this problem anymore. I disabled Bitnami layer to have a "normal" Linux box. It seems it was some problem with Bitnami's virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

> sudo pip install --upgrade requests

solved that for me